# How do I draw a white border on a black page ?

Tags: color

I use

```
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
```

to create a document with white text on black background.

I draw a border around the page using

```
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
```

or

```
\thisfancypage{%
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}\doublebox}{}
```

.

But I need to have white lines for the border, else they won't show up on the black page. How do I change or set the border line colours ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\thisfancypage{% 
\color{white}
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}\doublebox}{}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,lipsum}
\pagecolor{white}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtTextLowerLeft{\color{black}%
  \rule[-\footskip]{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\textheight+\footskip\relax}}}
\color{white}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would always add a `\relax` after a `\dimexpr` to terminate it explicitly: `\dimexpr\textheight+\footskip\relax`. You never know how the length argument is used in the macro internally.